# Factorial of a Number showing as undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to learn closures. There are lots of example using `if` statements to find the factorial. I'm trying to it do in `for` loop but the result it's showing as undefined.

My Code:

```
function factorial(num){

    var num = 5;

    function calculateFactorial(){

       for(i=num-1; i>=1; i--){
           num= num*i; // num *= i
       }
       return num;
    }
}

console.log(factorial());
```

Where did I get it wrong?

Comment: `factorial` doesn't return anything... you're also never calling `calculateFactorial`...

Comment: I got to know now. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use closure, then you need return from `factorial()`:

```
function factorial(foo){ 
    let num = foo;       
    function calculateFactorial(){
        for (let i = num - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            num = num * i;
        }
        return num;
    }
    return calculateFactorial;
 }

 let myFunc = factorial(10);
 console.log(myFunc());// Output: 3628800
```

Let me show more simplier and illustrative to me an example:

```
function fooFunction(foo){ 
    let num = foo;       
    function calculateFactorial(){
        num +=1;
        return num;
    }
    return calculateFactorial;
 }

 let myFunc = fooFunction(1);
 console.log(myFunc()); // Output: 2
 console.log(myFunc()); // Output: 3
 console.log(myFunc()); // Output: 4
 console.log(myFunc()); // Output: 5
```

Please, read this [cool answers at SO about what closure is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work). These are some highlights:

- Whenever you use function inside another function, a closure is used.
- A closure in JavaScript is like keeping a copy of all the local variables, just as they were when a function exited.
- It is probably best to think that a closure is always created just an entry to a function, and the local variables are added to that closure.
- A new set of local variables is kept every time a function with a closure is called (given that the function contains a function declaration inside it, and a reference to that inside function is either returned or an external reference is kept for it in some way).

Comment: there is no use of calculateFactorial function inside factorial, right

Comment: @Durga thanks for your attention. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you don't need another function `calculateFactorial` inside `factorial` function.

```js
function factorial(num){
    for(i=num-1; i>=1; i--){
        num= num*i; // num *= i
    }
    return num;
}
console.log( factorial(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution : 
(You need to call function inside also return needed )

```js
function factorial(num_){
   
    var num;
    if (typeof num_ === "undefined") { 
      num = 5;
    } else {
      num = num_;
    }

    var calculateFactorial = function(){

       for(var i=num-1; i>=1; i--){
           num= num*i; // num *= i
       }
       return num;
    }
    return calculateFactorial();
}

console.log(factorial(2));
```

Comment: this isn't a proper solution, as you are passing 2 and changing value of num to 5

Comment: I just copy code from Q . I don't want to write now library...

Answer (score 0):

correct way is:

```js
function factorial(num){

    function calculateFactorial(num){

       for(i=num-1; i>=1; i--){
           num= num*i; // num *= i
       }
       return num;
    }
    return calculateFactorial(num);
}

console.log(factorial(5));
```

What you're doing is first you are defining a function factorial which takes a num as a variable and inside this you are defining another function to actually calculate the result.So you are complicating the way

> Blockquote
>
> Blockquote